# Make columns of column values

Tags: r

I have this kind of data:

```
view(S)
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   Source                
   <chr>                 
 1 137                   
 2 137,111,43,34,34,43,22
 3 137                   
 4 137                   
 5 137,45,34,63,34,45,22 
 6 137,78,63             
 7 137.63                
 8 137                   
 9 137,83,78             
10 137,132,128
```

I want to make each distinct value as it´s own column and if the value is present in a row the value should be as an x, otherwise no value should be imputed.

Example:

```
  137 111 43 ...
1   x           
2   x   x  x
3   x
4   x
5   x
...
```

My Idea was to use the `separate` function and then replace all values which are not NA with an x:

```
library(tidyr)
separate(S, col = "Source", into = c("137", "111", "43"), sep = ",")


 # A tibble: 10 x 3
   x      Y     Z    
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>
 1 137    NA    NA   
 2 137    111   43   
 3 137    NA    NA   
 4 137    NA    NA   
 5 137    45    34   
 6 137    78    63   
 7 137.63 NA    NA   
 8 137    NA    NA   
 9 137    83    78   
10 137    132   128
```

However, in reality the amount of distinct numbers is much larger as in the example.

Here is a small dput:

```
structure(list(Source = c("137", "137,111,43,34,34,43,22", "137", 
"137", "137,45,34,63,34,45,22", "137,78,63", "137.63", "137", 
"137,83,78", "137,132,128")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following will do what you want.
Just get all unique values from `S` and use that as argument `into`.

```
into <- unique(unlist(strsplit(S[[1]], ",")))
separate(S, col = "Source", into = into, sep = ",")
```